# Is there a method like didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation which happens during rotation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to .StartAnimating an UIActivityIndicator when I rotate the device, I was trying to use an override function: didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation; however, this function is called after rotation has occurred and I would like to animate during the actual rotation.

I am looking for a method which is called at the moment of rotation. I have looked through the literature, and have found only depreciated functions that might have worked.

Are there any current methods that I could use for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use this code snippet to check the orientation changes 
**Swift 1.x/2.x**

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to begin the UIActivityIndicator like I'd like, but I seem to have lost the functionality of the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: I don´t know if that is possible actually. For instant recognition of device orientation change you're just gonna have to monitor the accelerometer yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code ,

**Swift 3.x**

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
      // Execute before rotation
    }) { _ in
        //Execute after rotation

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also able to use this:

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
```

Essentially, it allows for views to be used during the rotation. In my case, I have my UIActivityIndicator start animating when the rotation is detected. This is then followed by this code:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        print("Rotation did occur.")

// my code entries.
// my code entries..
// my code entries...

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()   
    }
```

At the end of the orientation transition, the activity indicator stops animating, and since I have ticked the Hides When Stopped option in the Attributes Inspector, it then disappears.